# PHP function on Blade directives

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using `@lang` from Blade directives to handle translations.

I'd like to use `PHP` function to act on this directive "return statement" in views, for example :

```
strtoupper(@lang('messages.test'))
```

Is that possible with Blade ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then don't use the blade helper.

```
{{ strtoupper(trans('messages.test')) }}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about trans helper. Thank you !